# Django - query filter on manytomany is exists

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have such a model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    # ...
    channels = models.ManyToManyField(Channel)
    # ...
```

What is the most effective way to fetch news related to channels?

Comment: To multiple channels? Or one channel?

Answer (score 11):

For a given channel, you can filter with:

```
News.object.filter(channels=my_channel)
```

for a collection (list, `QuerySet`, ...):

```
News.object.filter(channels__in=my_channel_collection)
```

For `News` objects that have at least *one* (or more) channels, we can query with:

```
News.objects.filter(channels__isnull=False).distinct()
```

or with `.exclude(..)`:

```
News.objects.exclude(channels=None)
```

Comment: But I want to find news having at least one any channel

Comment: @AlexanderFedotov: so you mean you want to exclude `News` objects that have no channel, right?

Answer (score 3):

This is more complicated than it seems. I have a model `Step` with an `ingredients` m2m field. Only 603 is correct :)

```
>>> Step.objects.count()
735
>>> Step.objects.filter(ingredients=True).count()
159
>>> Step.objects.exclude(ingredients=False).count()
735
>>> Step.objects.exclude(ingredients=None).count()
603
>>> Step.objects.filter(ingredients__isnull=False).distinct().count()
603
>>> Step.objects.filter(ingredients__isnull=False).count()
59310
>>> sum([step.ingredients.exists() for step in Step.objects.all()])
603
```